# Is there an alternative to Ghost peer to peer disk cloning?

Tags: hard-drive, software-rec, disk-image

I am looking for a way to replace ghost peer-to-peer (slave/master) disk cloning over network.
but after searching, I couldn't find a good software replacement.
would anyone please suggest some?

NOTE: I do not want to create image of hard disk. just need to clone one computer hard disk to another over LAN

Comment: [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)?

Comment: I dont think clonezilla has a feature that directly clones a hard drive on another machine like peer to peer in Ghost, is that right? what i want is that no image file is created, just direct cloning

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  There might be some better solution you haven't come across yet, depending on why you need to clone disks over the network without making images.

Comment: because it's faster to just clone disk between two computers with cross-over cable rather than download image from network.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org). I don't remember the exact steps, but the two key choices are to select device to device cloning.

[image]

And instead of using local devices. Select one of the networking options.

[image]